# Storing each key value of dictionary as a separate numpy array with key name as its name and concatenating it into a large array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

The file uploaded to python is stored in the form of a dictionary. The dictionary has about 181 unique key names in the form of string and values in the form of 2D array float64. The key names and its values association is quite important. I need to save each key value as an numpy array with the corresponding key name as its array name for referring and finally consolidated 2d array of the individual arrays. These are later fed into neural networks.

```
keys = vals = []

for k, v in matsd.items():
    keys.append(k)
    vals.append(v)

matsdkeys1 = np.array(keys)
matsdvals1 = np.array(vals)
```

The above code creates an array of object which is not useful. Required some guidance for to proceed further.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLfy6.png)

Comment: " I need to save each key value as an numpy array with the corresponding key name as its array name for referring " What do you mean, exactly? What does "as its array name for referring" mean? What, **exactly** is the output you expect?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga For example based on the image attached if you take the first key name 'K1000tn1' it has its corresponding value in array of   size 225*100  type float64. The array should be named or the variable name should be k1000tn1 stroring it's corresponding value. Similarly for each key and its corresponding value separately. At the end the concateneated array of these arrays with user defined name

Comment: Don't dynamically create variable names? What's the point? Just *use the `dict`*. And *what do you mean by a user-defined name*? Again, *don't dynamically create variables*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my terminologies to address the problem might not be that of a good programmer.  I understand not to create the variables dynamically but for training neural network I need this dictionary keys to be to be unpacked and save it's corresponding value. User defined name here just the name of choice given by the user to call the concatenated arrays.

Comment: "I need this dictionary keys to be to be unpacked and save it's corresponding value" Again, **what does that mean exactly**? Provide a small example. And yet again, you *shouldn't* dynamically create variables and there *is no need for you to*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for responding. I got my solution like ``` for key,val in mats8d.items():
        exec(key + '=val') ```